# 'Observable<{}|Object[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Object[]>' Angular Typescript Error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm facing the following syntax error: `'Observable<{}|Page[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Page[]>' Angular Typescript Error` with the following service method:

```
  getAuthRoutes(): Observable<Page[]> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    return this.http.post<Page[]>(this.Url + '/AuthRoutes', null, { headers })
      .pipe(
      tap(objects => console.log("Authorizated routes, OK!", objects)),
        catchError(error => throwError(error))
      );
  }
```

The strange thing of all this is that the code above works fine if I launch debug of the app (I can launch it because the error appears a little bit after compiling).

The error seems to be related to the `catchError(error => throwError(error))` part of the method, which uses rxjs's `throwError` function to throw an error observable in case of error.

Does anyone know how to fix that? Is there any improvement that I can do on my code in order to fix this?

Comment: The stream's value in the error case isn't a `Page[]`, so your function's return type is inaccurate. How to fix that depends on the behaviour you want: you need to change either the signature or the error handling.

Comment: Given that all you do when you catch the error is throw it again, why don't you just leave that part out entirely?

Comment: @jonrsharpe first of all, thanks you very much for your explaination and for your fast answer! By now, I haven't a real behavior need for the error catching (to give you an example, a simple console.log could be also fine for this). What do you mean with "leave that part out entirely" exactly? Should I delete all of the catchError management code?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50246811/6680611

Comment: I gladly report that **both cartant's and jonrsharpe's solutions are working**, thank you guys! Also using a custom error Handling function that I've made works. In this function, I log the error and then explicitly return an empty result. I found it on [mayorsanmayor's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041698/angular-ts-error-ts1109?rq=1) that I've found in the past for a previous problem. I consider this problem solved and fixed as well now!